# Get latest 4 post on a custom post filtered by category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm trying to get the latest 4 posts filtered by category.
My post type are products.

I already tried wp_get_recent_posts, but it doesn't have an attribute for category filter.

Then i tried with the WP_Query, but is not working too.

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'category' => '30278'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args2);
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
```

It shows me always the same posts.

This is my recent post code:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'include' => get_cat_ID($atts['category']),
);
wp_get_recent_posts($args, $atts['category']);
```

I tried to add in my args include, exclude, category and category name. without results.
I really don't know how to solve this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since your taxonomy is `product_cat` you need to run a taxonomy query. The `category` isn't working because a `product_cat` isn't technically a `category`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference and either custom `WP_Query` or `wp_get_recent_posts` should work like a charm in this case. (To be honest, `wp_get_recent_posts` uses `get_posts and this one is based on`WP_Query`).

So the problem is not with methods you're trying to use, but the way you use them...

### `wp_get_recent_posts`

`wp_get_recent_posts` function takes two arguments:

- $args - list of arguments that describe the posts you want to get,
- $output - constant OBJECT, ARRAY_A which describes how the result will be formatted.

So let's take a look at your call of that function:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'include' => get_cat_ID($atts['category']),
);
wp_get_recent_posts($args, $atts['category']);
```

You put `$atts['category']` as second argument, so the `$output` argument is incorrect. And even worse - you put category ID as `include` argument, which should be a list of posts that should be included...

**How to make it work?**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 30278,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
) );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

### WP_Query

So why the WP_Query method doesn't work?

Take a look at possible parameters of WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

There is no parameter called `taxonomy`, so this one will be ignored.

There is also no `category` param, so this one will be ignored too.

And how to make it work? Easy - just use the same `$args` as in `wp_get_recent_posts` call above.